# Trouble toggling between (CSS) functions

Tags: jquery

```
$(".m").toggle(
    $(".m").addClass('on'),
    $(".m").removeClass('on') 
);
```

This doesn't seem to work the way I want it to, am I doing this wrong or is it something else?

I tried your ways, they seemed to work but this problem is in the css, its not showing .on, it looks like this:

```
    a.m {color:red;}
    a.m:hover {color:blue;}
    a.m:active, .on {color:green;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using `.toggleClass()`

```
$(".m").toggleClass("on")
```

---

Reference: [.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

> ***Description**: Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the switch argument.*

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap them in functions, like this:

```
$(".m").toggle(function() {
   $(".m").addClass('on');
}, function() {
    $(".m").removeClass('on')
} );
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/